# Bench press abs workout

Tags: workout

I am thinking of buying  a bench press for abs.Will it be good enough to increase my abs size ? Of course I am doing and right nutrient but I want just to know if it will help to be big..Thanks a lot

Comment: Bench pressing isn't really an ab-focused exercise though.

Comment: I know but it can help a lot i think ,I am not sure

Comment: If this is a decline bench, you can get a decent ab workout on it. A flat bench will not provide you any more benefit than doing situps off the floor.

Comment: Yes it is decline bench

Answer (score -1):

A more effective exercise would be leg raises from bar which you can do pull ups on and possibly attach rings to do a variety of exercises.